# Sorting an Single Singly Linked list

Tags: java, sorting, collections, linked-list

Is there any way or method in java Collection framework through which we can sort a singly Linked list directly as we do with lists. ex Collections.sort(lists);

Comment: Is this your own singly linked list class?

Comment: This is **your** homework not our. Try to solve it by yourself and come back if you have a specific problem.

Comment: Sorry to say but this isn't my homework I was solving a leetcode question where I have to merge a list of LinkedList and then have to sort the linked list. I have merged the List of Linked List in a Linked List but couldn't able to sort it directly therefore asked a doubt whether it can be sort directly or not. But I think you misunderstood my question don't know why you replied like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the (hypothetical) singly linked list implements the `java.util.List` interface, then you can sort it using `Collections.sort`.  Otherwise, it cannot be done using the (standard) Java collections framework.

You could ... of course ... copy the (hypothetical) linked list elements to (say) an `ArrayList`, sort that using `Collections.sort`, then copy the elements of the sorted `ArrayList` back replacing the linked list elements.

---

> Please try to answer the question in Java.

English is sufficiently expressive in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was also thinking the same but I thought there might be some method in Collections framework through which we can achieve this. But your answer clarified my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.Collections` contains the `Collections.sort();` function. Within that the `Collections.reverseOrder()` can be utilised.

For example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;  
import java.util.Collections;  //import Collections
import java.util.List;  
public class TestList  
{  
public static void main(String args[])   
    {  
        List<Integer> testList = Arrays.asList(5,4,3,2,1);  
        Collections.sort(testList, Collections.reverseOrder()); //use Collections to reverse the list order
        System.out.println(testList);  
    }  
}
```

The resultant console output would be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`